# Populating a HashMap with entries from a properties file

Tags: java, hashmap

I want to populate a `HashMap` using the `Properties` class. 
I want to load the entries in the `.propeties` file and then copy it into the `HashMap`.

Earlier, I used to just initialize the `HashMap` with the properties file, but now I have already defined the `HashMap` and want to initialize it in the constructor only.

Earlier approach:

```
Properties properties = new Properties();

try {
    properties.load(ClassName.class.getResourceAsStream("resume.properties"));
} catch (Exception e) { 

}

HashMap<String, String> mymap= new HashMap<String, String>((Map) properties);
```

But now, I have this

```
public class ClassName {
HashMap<String,Integer> mymap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

public ClassName(){

    Properties properties = new Properties();

    try {
      properties.load(ClassName.class.getResourceAsStream("resume.properties"));
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
    mymap = properties;
    //The above line gives error
}
}
```

How do I assign the properties object to a `HashMap` here?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

If I understand correctly, each value in the properties is a String which represents an Integer. So the code would look like this:

```
for (String key : properties.stringPropertyNames()) {
    String value = properties.getProperty(key);
    mymap.put(key, Integer.valueOf(value));
}
```

Comment: In case you're getting **null when using getResourceAsStream**, it's probably because you're looking for file outside classpath. So to read an absolute file path, you can do:  `File file = new File("absolute/file/path/resume.properties");
   FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
   properties.load(fileInputStream);
   fileInputStream.close();`

Answer (score 25):

Use `.entrySet()`

```
for (Entry<Object, Object> entry : properties.entrySet()) {
    map.put((String) entry.getKey(), (String) entry.getValue());
}
```

Answer (score 13):

Java 8 Style:

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
// add  some properties  here
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap();

map.putAll(properties.entrySet()
                     .stream()
                     .collect(Collectors.toMap(e -> e.getKey().toString(), 
                                               e -> e.getValue().toString())));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public static Map<String,String> getProperty()
    {
        Properties prop = new Properties();
        Map<String,String>map = new HashMap<String,String>();
        try
        {
            FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(Constants.PROPERTIESPATH);
            prop.load(inputStream);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Some issue finding or loading file....!!! " + e.getMessage());

        }
        for (final Entry<Object, Object> entry : prop.entrySet()) {
            map.put((String) entry.getKey(), (String) entry.getValue());
        }
        return map;
    }
```

Comment: Can you provide some explanation?

Comment: What is does  is just read properties file fill in map with  key and value. GetProperty() just return Map with key and value. you simplly access the value by doing like getProperty().get("key")

Answer (score 0):

you can use the below Method to load the property file in a map

```
public static Map<String, String> getProperties(String filePropertyFile){
        Properties getProperties = new Properties();
        FileInputStream inputStream = null;
        HashMap<String, String> propertyMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
        try {
            inputStream = new FileInputStream(filePropertyFile);
            getProperties.load(inputStream);
            propertyMap.putAll((Map) getProperties);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return propertyMap;
    }
```

**Unit Test:**

```
@Test
public void getPropertiesTest()
    String outputOmJarArrayAttributesPath = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/src/main/resources/OutputOmJarArrayAttributes.properties";
    System.out.println(PropertyFileUtils.getProperties(outputOmJarArrayAttributesPath));;
    }
```